# Putting HTML content in a Event label of Google Tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to pull an HTML element document.body.getElementsByClassName ("h4 margin-left")[0].innerHTML.replace(/\s+/g, ''); into a event tag of Google Tag Manager, but I don't seem to be able to get the data in.

I would expect to be able to use a Custom Javascript based variable in GTM, but that doesn't work. Although that the statement above does return the correct string when using the Console tab in Google Chrome

Comment: Can you post screenshots of how you are getting that value into your event tag? Did you define a variable for it?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom javascript variable should be

function(){
    return(document.body.getElementsByClassName ("h4 margin-left")[0].innerHTML.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
}

If that doesn't help please share a screenshot of your event tag, trigger and variable

kind regards

Analytics ML